# Calling javascript

Tags: javascript, package

I am setting up a site that relies on a lot of javascript items and i want to try and set it up so the pages only call what they need.
there are different types of functionality so i am goig to break them into their own js files to make it easy to use.
For example if there is a drag and drop functionality then i will include the js file for drag and drop. within that will be a generic call using a class to turn on the functionality. This way it is only used on a page that uses drag and drop.

This gets more compacted when i have ajax calls some are on change events on a select for example while others are on a button.
I could separate these into different files for each type perhaps.

my concern is if a call needs more parameters to be passed or a different url then where does this code go to make the call?

I don't really want to have code within the page itself if i can help it.

I would love to hear your thoughts on how to best set this up

Comment: what is your server side language?

Comment: in this project i only have access to Velocity (from java) so i am writing a macro to only put certain js files onto the page according to functionality.

Answer (score 1):

[RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) might be your answer:

> RequireJS is a JavaScript file and module loader. It is optimized for
>   in-browser use, but it can be used in other JavaScript environments,
>   like Rhino and Node. Using a modular script loader like RequireJS will
>   improve the speed and quality of your code.

Comment: his does look very good and will help simplify parts of it but I'm still struggling to figure out the best approach for where to put the actual calls to the functions.

As an example i have a generic ajax script takes a few parameters such as the url to use. then on one page i make a call to this function and pass in the url to use plus the call sets what to do with the results. this is on a per page basis. Where should i put this call to the function? At the moment i have put them in the page but should i put them in their own page.js file perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds similar to what I'm doing, so here what I've done:

- One central file that contains functions that are used pretty much everywhere.
- A folder containing files that are used in several places, but aren't worth including everywhere.
- A folder containing files that are only used on one page.

Then, simply include the necessary `<script>` tags and go!

Comment: This is how I'm set up at the moment but it is not ideal as it means all your function calls are on each page and id rather they were all in one place.

Answer (score -1):

Hmm, have you looked at existing frameworks http://speckyboy.com/2010/05/17/15-javascript-web-ui-libraries-frameworks-and-libraries/?

Comment: thanks for the link but my question isn't about what functionality to use but more about how to call it in the easiest and simplest way.